# How to convert a raw file to png in Android?

Tags: android, android-image

I got an app, this app downloads many pictures, but i store them with my own format. This is because i dont want android system to show them in Gallery, so these are my own pictures.

I want to send them via email but firstly i want to convert them to .png of course.

How can i convert a File to png in Java(Android) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `.nomedia` file in your folder. Or make your format just regular png but with extra custom header attached, so you will not have to convert, just write a copy with your header skipped